# JFrame isn't painting after creating it with a button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I want to have titlescreen and open a game by clicking a button. When i call the play()-method of my project normally, it draws the first level. But when i call it with a button, a white screen appeares and I dont know why. Here is a code snippet:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Game implements ActionListener {
    private String csvFile;
    private JFrame titlescreen;
    private JButton startButton;

public Game(String csvFile){
    this.csvFile = csvFile;
}

public void prepare(){
    titlescreen = new JFrame("Titlescreen");
    titlescreen.setSize(100,100);
    startButton = new JButton("Start Game");
    startButton.addActionListener(this);

    titlescreen.add(startButton);
    titlescreen.setVisible(true);
}

public void play(){
    titlescreen.setVisible(false);
    if(csvFile!= null) {
        LevelBuilder levelBuilder = new LevelBuilder(csvFile, ";", ",");

        AllObstacles ao = new AllObstacles();
        ao.addObstaclesOfString(levelBuilder.getLvlString(), ";", ",");
        Goal g = new Goal(125, 125, 250, 250);
        PlayGame c = new PlayGame(ao, g, levelBuilder);
        c.create();
        c.play();
    }
 }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    startButton.dispatchEvent(e);
    play();
}
}
```

Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: *When i call the play()-method of my project normally,* - I assume you mean in the main() method. In this case the code executes on a non EDT Thread. *But when i call it with a button,* - the code executes on the EDT which is the code responsible for responding to events and painting the GUI. So I would guess you have some looping code with prevents repainting. For a game don't use looping code. Instead use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation of the game.  Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Also, I have no idea why you invoke dispatchEvent() in your ActionListener. I would get rid of that code, or redesign your class if you think that is necessary.

Comment: I suspect `startButton.dispatchEvent(e);` is creating an infinite loop, which in turn prevents the window from painting.  As camickr said, remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Please see you have `play()` method used inside of `play()` method. Please try to change ones name. Maybe you are just calling wrong method inside of `actionPerformed()` method.

If that won't work, you can try deleting whole `play(){...}` and `actionPerformed(){...}` methods from your snippet and delete line:

```
startButton.addActionListener(this);
```

Then you can just add this into your prepare() function:

```
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(csvFile!= null) {
                   titlescreen.dispose();
                   LevelBuilder levelBuilder = new LevelBuilder(csvFile, ";", ",");
                   AllObstacles ao = new AllObstacles();
                   ao.addObstaclesOfString(levelBuilder.getLvlString(), ";", ",");
                   Goal g = new Goal(125, 125, 250, 250);
                   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new PlayGame(ao, g, levelBuilder);
            }
        });
```

It will add to your button new ActionListener that:

- disposes titlescreen (you do not need it running in background)
- runs new PlayGame object in new thread (to avoid lags especially if you have any timer in your game)

Moreover:

```
c.create()
c.play()
```

you are using those two methods everytime you create new PlayGame object, so you should put them into constructor of PlayGame class, so:

```
public PlayGame(){
//your current code
create();
play();
}
```